# addEventListener to a Button ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, performance

```js
console.clear();

function my_Func() {
  //I have a lot of code in this Function Which Is Confusing
  document.querySelector('#return-toggle').addEventListener('click', e => {
    return_status = "yes";
    alert("Hello!!!!")
  });
}

my_Func()
my_Func()
my_Func()
my_Func()
```

```html
<button id="return-toggle">Display Alert </button>
```

Basically, I used query selector to trigger id of button. My code requires some function to be called multiple times including the buttons. In my code above, `myFunc()` is called 3 times but when I click on the Display Alert Button, it alerted 3 times instead of 1 time. I want the button to be triggered 1 time only and not multiple times even if my_Func() is called multiple times. May I know if there is a way to alert() 1 time only when the query selector is called multiple times?

I am not sure if removing duplicates of query selector will work.

Comment: `my_Func()` could set a global variable the first time it's called. If the variable is set, don't add the event listener again.

Comment: Typically you're supposed to add  `eventListener` only once for a single event handling. If you need to run `my_Func()` call multiple times, you might want to pull the `addEventListener` block out of `my_Func` into a separate method. Then invoke the `addEventListener` only once, and you can call `my_Func` as many times as you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass the same function reference to `addEventListener`, then the event listener will be considered to have been added only once.

```js
function handleClick(e) {
  console.log('click listener');
}
function my_Func() {
  document.querySelector('#return-toggle').addEventListener('click', handleClick);
}
my_Func();
my_Func();
my_Func();
my_Func();
```

```html
<button id="return-toggle">Click</button>
```

However, in general, you should set up event listeners only once, usually on page load.